# Zsh completion for mounts (/run/media/DISK-LABEL)?

Tags: mount, zsh, autocomplete

I am looking or `zsh` functionality to expand disk-labels into mountpoins:

Example: I have disk  with label `DISK-LABEL1` mounted on `/run/media/god/DISK-LABEL1`.

Is there a plugin which expands input Like:  `cat //DISK-LA<Tab>` to the `cat /run/media/god/DISK-LABEL1`?

"**//**" was chosen as an example to trigger that type of autocompletion...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to trigger completion on `//`, I think you'll have to modify [`_path_files`](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Type/_path_files). I don't recommend it.

Or maybe it's possible by defining a [`file-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) style, but I can't see how.

If you make `god` a named directory for `/run/media/god`, then you can use `~god` to refer to that directory. This works whether you use completion or not. This has the side effect that `/run/media/god` will appear as `~god` in your prompt.

```
hash -d god=/run/media/god
```

Comment: Using "god" here is probably not a good choice as that's likely to be the username.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to define a function to do what you wait:

```
mountbylabel () {
  mount /run/media/god/$1
}
```

and put that in your `.zshrc`. Then, create a completion function for it:

```
#compdef mountbylabel

compadd "${(@f)$(ls /run/media/god)}"
```

And put that in a file called `_mountbylabel` inside your fpath somewhere. I store all my completion function files in `~/.zsh/completions/` and have

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completions $fpath)
```

in my `.zshrc`.

Comment: The question isn't asking for completions to `mount`, it's asking for completion that can be used anywhere a file name is expected.